# Toastr in Angular 16 is not popping

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

// --- app.module.ts

```
...
  imports: [
    ....
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 1000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
    }),
    ....
  ],
...
```

// --- app.module.ts

// --- Component in child module

```
...
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._toastr.success('DC Retrived',  'Toaster test', {
      timeOut: 3000,
    });
  }
...
```

// --- Component in child module

I tried importing the toastr css in app.module.scss and in angular.json and nothing worked.

Comment: Please elaborate the code and write good descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `ngOnInit` is too soon. Try this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this._toastr.success('DC Retrived',  'Toaster test', {
    timeOut: 3000,
  });
}
```

And in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
]
```

Note you will have to restart the Angular dev server to pick up changes in `angular.json`

Answer (score 0):

The problem With me was importing the toastr.css file like this in the "**angular.json**" file.

```json
"styles": [
  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
]
```

When I imported the file in **"styles.scss"** Every thing showed up again

```scss
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr';
```